# Barbalat’s Lemma to show the stability of equilibrium point x=0

Tags: nonlinear-system

I have this problem to solve:

Use Barbalat’s Lemma to show the stability of equilibrium point $x=0$ for the system $\dot{x}=-x+p\sin(t)$ and $\dot{p}=-p\sin(t)$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! It is customary for users to also mention their thought process and what they have tried so far, as well as relevant definitions.

Comment: A quick search for Barbalat’s Lemma and some poking around will find a solution quickly.

Comment: @copper.hat  can you offer me suitable lyapunov function?